# How is the total spin of a particle actually measured?

Tags: angular-momentum, quantum-spin, fermions, measurements

Say I have a fermion whose total spin I do not know. I then use a stern gerlach setup to measure $S_z$. If I find +1/2, I could say that the total spin is $1/2$. But it could also be the eigenket $|3/2,1/2>$.

- Mathematically to evaluate the $3/2$ I could apply the $S^2$ operator and obtain this simultaneously with $S_z$ if I wanted, but how is this done physically?

Comment: Book recommendation: “The Story of Spin,” by Tomonaga.

Answer (score 5):

Usually, when you are trying to measure a particle's spin, you do not have only one particle at hand. Rather you have a stream of particles. The reason you require this stream of particles is because the **"measurement"** in quantum mechanics is completely **random phenomena.** All you can say about a measurement is *What is the probability that I get a certain result?*

So when you have stream of 3/2 spin particles and you do the Stern-Gerlach experiment on them you will see **every possible eigenstate** as the **result of measurement**. So a spin-1/2 particle will only give you two separate lines after measurement( |1/2,1/2> and |1/2,-1/2>) whereas from a 3/2-spin particle you'll get 4 such states (|3/2,-3/2>,|3/2,-1/2>,|3/2,1/2>,|3/2,3/2>). Then you'll know for sure.

Comment: I was thinking that, but I' find the one particle case strange. If you measured a spin of 1/2, does that imply the particle is in a superposition of all possible particles with at least this spin? For example between an electron(1/2), and a gravitino(3/2)?

Comment: If you measure the spin of one particle to be spin-1/2 it only means that the particle is in a state for which Sz is 1/2. It does not imply the particle to be in any superposition state. In this case the lack of knowledge is not an intrinsic property of the system.

Comment: also you could do multiple measurements for this particle by rotating the setup...